# Copy some lines in a file to another file using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, full-text-search

I am a novice to VB scripting and was trying to work on a file handling.

I was trying to write a script which reads an xml file and copies all data between the `<Text>` and `</Text>` tags to a new file. This should happen for all `<Text>` and `</Text>` sections in the file.

My text file is as follows.

```
<Text>    M3XAUDT-A           FILE M30000            --- AUDIT TRAIL STATISTICS ---     RUN   TUESDAY 07/02/02 AT 23:21     PAGE    1
                                            RECORD COUNTS FOR CAE ON FILE M2AUD

</Text>
</Page>
<Page>
<Text>    M3XAUDT-A           FILE M30000            --- AUDIT TRAIL STATISTICS ---     RUN   TUESDAY 07/02/02 AT 23:21     PAGE    2
                                            RECORD COUNTS FOR CAE ON FILE M3AUD
</Text>
</Page>
<Page>
<Text>    M3XAUDT-A           FILE M30000            --- AUDIT TRAIL STATISTICS ---     RUN   TUESDAY 07/02/02 AT 23:21     PAGE    3
                                            RECORD COUNTS FOR CAE ON FILE M2AUD
</Text>
```

Before i would start creating a new file to copy the sections, i thought I could see whether the right data has been picked up using a msgbox.

I tried with the below script, but it fails by going into a loop after displaying the 1st line.

```
Dim fso2, objStream2, strline, strline1,

set fso2=Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if fso2.fileExists("C:\Harsha\1_Test\Source\APE_new.xml") then
set objStream2 = fso2.OpenTextFile("C:\Harsha\1_Test\Source\APE_new.xml")
i=1
do while not objStream2.AtEndOfStream
        strline= strline & objStream2.Readline &vbNewLine
        do while instr(strline,"<Text>") 
                strline1=strline1&objStream2.Readline &vbNewLine
                msgbox strline1
        do until instr(strline1,"</Text>") 
        strline2=strline2&strline1
        loop
            msgbox strline2
        loop
loop

end if
ObjStream2.close
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim fso2, objStream2, strline, strline1, isReading
set fso2=Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
isReading = false
if fso2.fileExists("C:\Harsha\1_Test\Source\APE_new.xml") then
  set objStream2 = fso2.OpenTextFile("C:\Harsha\1_Test\Source\APE_new.xml")
  i=1
  do while not objStream2.AtEndOfStream
    strline= objStream2.Readline
    if instr(strline,"<Text>") then
      isReading = true
    end if
    if isReading = true then
      strline1 = strline1 & strline & vbNewLine
      msgbox "Read: " & strline
    endif
    if instr(strlin,"</Text>") then
       isReading = false
       msgbox "End of text, str is: " & strline1 & " , resetting strline1 var now"
       strline1 = ""
    end if
  loop
  objStream2.close 
end if
```